# In Excel, how do I fill down a value a specific number of times?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Basically, I have different 1,000 assignments in column A. And in column B, I want to place a name to assign those in column A.

Some names will receive 30 assignments, some names will receive 50 assignments, and some names will receive 80 assignments. Is there a way to fill these names down without manually dragging out and counting each time?

Comment: The most basic way would be to use the GoTo function (keyboard shortcut `F5`) and type in the bottom cell, copy it, then ctrl+shift+up and paste in the value for those cells.  Repeat the process for the next name and so on.

Comment: If you're looking for something automated, you could probably do this with a formula if built a reference table with the names and how many rows they need to be copied into, or it could be done with VBA